# Optimization of an algorithm using apply inestead of two fors in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I've got a following problem:

I want to reorganise my table from:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,0,1), B=c(1,0,1), C=c(0,1,1))

  A  B  C
x 1  1  0
y 0  0  1
z 1  1  1
```

Into a frame:

```
  AB  AC  BC
x  1   0   0
y  0   0   0
z  1   1   1
```

By using a conjunction of each column.

I can do it by using two for functions, but it is really time consuming on "big data" and  I'm looking for an optimisation function. I find out that `apply` can be useful in that case, but I have no idea how can I use it in that case.

Can someone give me a hint, how to solve above problem?

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to "optimize"

Comment: To get the same result but faster than using for in for.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what exactly you want to optimize? The more information you provide, the more likely it is to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: By optimizing I mean that:
1. I want the algorithm to be as fast as possible. 
For now that is the only thing I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work using a combination of lapply and dplyr.
It makes a list of the product of the columns, which is then bound into a single dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(1:(ncol(df)-1), function(n){
  out <- df[,n] * df 
  names(out)  <- paste0(names(df)[n] ,names(df))
  out %>% select(c((n+1):ncol(df)))
}) %>% bind_cols()
```